# How pass an smarty array at a php page with an sbmit button

Tags: php, html

I have to pass an array (result from a table) to a PHP page. `$dataResource` is my array, which I have to send to `Page.php`:

```
<a href="../../Page.php?d={$dataResources}" id="">
  <input type="button" value="Create" style="float: right;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the `json_encode` function as a modifier for `$dataResources`.

```
<a href="../../Page.php?d={$dataResource|@json_encode|rawurlencode}" id="">
```

And in php, reverse the operation with `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode($_GET['d'], true);
```

Comment: Can you post the generated url?

Comment: Yes is this: ../../Page.php?d=null